# How to import deployed contact on public testnet into remix

Tags: solidity, remix, rinkeby, javascript-vm

I see that there are lots of information on how to deploy your contact to rinkbey using remix but not vice versa. I want to copy deployed contact from rinkbey testnet to local Blockchain simulator like remix. How could I do so?

I understand that I can go to etherscan get the bytecode and abi. But what is the code in solidity that enables me to use this information to deploy it to the local Blockchain simulator such as remix JavaScript VM.

Can you please provide a simple workable code that you tried?

Comment: @cameel no, it does not! :S

Comment: I mean, this is an automatic comment that SE adds when you mark a question a duplicate :) Anyway, can you explain what's different about this question? Both ask about the same thing, one just has Rinkeby in the title, the other has it only in tags and is slightly more generic. If it's just about making it more general then I think that the old question should have just been edited instead. If there's actually a significant difference, please adjust the title to make it obvious.